# Will logging into Chrome erase the settings I currently have?

Tags: google-chrome

I started using Google Chrome a long time ago, but when I got my current laptop I never actually logged into Chrome. Now I have a lot of settings and bookmarks on Chrome on my laptop, but they are not under my account; when I logged into Chrome under my name the other day on another computer, all of my old settings showed up. My question is, is there any way for me to transfer the settings/bookmarks that I currently have on my Chrome to my account? I figure that if I log into my account it will erase all of the settings that I currently have and replace them with the ones that are technically 'mine' from my account. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Just copy your profile folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**is there any way for me to transfer the settings/bookmarks that I currently have on my Chrome to my account?**

google-chromeYes and no. Only your bookmarks can be transferred. Settings will sync, but to my knowledge, you cannot transfer them.

"Open Chrome.
At the top right, click Menu Menu.
Select Bookmarks and then Bookmark Manager.
In the manager, click the "Organize" menu.
Select Export bookmarks."

Then of course import them.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en

I figure that if I log into my account it will erase all of the settings that I currently have and replace them with the ones that are technically 'mine' from my account. Is there a way to avoid that?

Yes and No. Your favorites will merge but all other settings will be overwritten.